# capybara how to find to get the result in html or multiline text?

Tags: ruby, capybara, capybara-webkit

There's a html code

```
<p>
test text
<br/>
test2
<p/>
```

When performing the method:

```
.find(:xpath, "/html/p").text
```

result:

```
test text test2
```

How can I get the "two lines"

```
test text
test2
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't have `<br>` tags inside a `<p>` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Capybara tries to follow the webdriver spec when it makes sense, which means `#text` returns normalized text content with carriage returns/linefeeds removed and therefore doesn't fulfill your needs.

**Unfortunately capybara-webkit doesn't return element properties when accessed through `#[]` so this won't work with capybara-webkit - it should work with selenium or poltergeist though**

However, since you're using one of the real browser drivers (not rack-test) you should be able to access the elements innerText property by doing

```
find(:xpath, "/html/p")['innerText']
```

which should provide the output you're looking for

Comment: Returns nil :), how can you can get html?

Comment: HTML i managed to get here so  find(:xpath, "/html/p").base.inner_html , but how to get the text? A similar method Inner text is not working

Comment: hmmm -- seems like capybara-webkit doesn't return element properties when accessed through `#[]` like the other real browser drivers do (selenium, poltergeist).  What you want may not be possible with capybara-webkit - updating answer to reflect that it's not valid for capybara-webkit